# Reverse for 'surveyanalysis' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['surveyanalysis/(?P<Survey_Question_No>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

**my html template looks like this:**

```
    <a href="{% url 'SurveyAnalysis:surveyanalysis' Survey_Question_No %}">ANALYZE RESULTS</a><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**views.py look like this**

```
def surveyanalysis(request,Survey_Question_No):
    surveyresponse = get_object_or_404(SurveyResponseDetails, id=Survey_Question_No)

    

   # start working for Chart
    labels = [] #empty labels for storing labels
    data = [] #empty data for storing data
    default_data=[] #empty default_data for storing default_data
    default_labels=[] #empty default_labels for storing default_labels

   #filtering total Radio type Question Responses
    queryset = SurveyResponseDetails.objects.order_by('Survey_Question_Desc').values('Survey_Question_Answer').filter(Survey_Question_No=Survey_Question_No).annotate(Survey_Question_Desc_count=Count('Survey_Question_Desc'))
    
    for response in queryset:
        
        
        data = list(queryset.values_list('Survey_Question_Desc_count', flat=True))
        labels = list(queryset.values_list('Survey_Question_Answer', flat=True))
 
    return render(request, 'survey-analysis/surveyanalysis.html', {
       
         'surveyresponse':surveyresponse
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
       
        })
```

**my urls look like this**

```
  from django.urls import path
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from . import views
 from django.views import View
 app_name='SurveyAnalysis'

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
 urlpatterns = [

 path('surveyanalysis/<int:Survey_Question_No>/', views.surveyanalysis, name='surveyanalysis'),
 path('question', views.surveyanalysis, name='question'),

   ]
```

Usually I could easily read where the error is coming from and deal with it but in this case I can't spot the cause of the error hence I'm unable to progress with my study. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both of the URLs are dispatching request to the same function with different inputs. You need to define default value for Survey_Question_No to handle question URL.

Comment: Could you please write the requested URL which caused this error?

Comment: <a href="{% url 'SurveyAnalysis:surveyanalysis' Survey_Question_No %}">ANALYZE RESULTS</a><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because Survey_Question_No is empty when you use it in the {% url ... %}

You have only surveyresponse, labels and data in your context sent to the render() ... you need to ad add 'Survey_Questio_No':xy

```
return render(request, 'survey-analysis/surveyanalysis.html', {
      
         'surveyresponse':surveyresponse
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
       
        })
```

Comment: No, in the database Survey_Question_No is not empty

Comment: I dont see Survey_xxxx  in the context that you pass to the renderer. So for the tag it has no value.

Comment: **error in this line**    <a href="{% url 'SurveyAnalysis:surveyanalysis' surveyresponse.Survey_question_No %}">ANALYZE RESULTS</a><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Comment: **i have changed my Views.py according to you but it is not working**         return render(request, 'survey-analysis/surveyanalysis.html', {
      
         'surveyresponse':surveyresponse
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
          'Survey_Question_No':surveyresponse

        })

Comment: Your original {% url   ... %}  was ok ... you just needed to correct the context (which you did now).

Comment: If you like to double check just somewhere print the value to make sure it is correct in your render context for the html page: {{Survey_Question_No}}